# Variables come zero when I call from another class

Tags: c#, object

This is my class that I am using to keep all values. In this class I used object oriented model,
but whenever if I want to call in Form2.cs I am not able to reach values properly.
If I call the variables in Form1.cs there is a no problem at all.

***class1.cs***

```
public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
          
        }
        public Class1(double Yb, double Yz, double Yd, double Cz, double Fz, double qT, double Kt, double Qs, double Sds, double r, double  genislikDeger1, double genislikDeger2, double genislikDeger3, double genislikDeger4, double yukselikDeger1, double yukselikDeger2, double yukselikDeger3, double yukselikDeger4, double ust, double kUst, double l)
        {
            this.genislikDeger1 = genislikDeger1;
            this.genislikDeger2 = genislikDeger2;
            this.genislikDeger3 = genislikDeger3;
            this.genislikDeger4 = genislikDeger4;
            this.yukselikDeger1 = yukselikDeger1;
            this.yukselikDeger2 = yukselikDeger2;
            this.yukselikDeger3 = yukselikDeger3;
            this.yukselikDeger4 = yukselikDeger4;
            this.ust = ust;
            this.kUst = kUst;
            this.L = l;
            this.Yb = Yb;
            this.Yz = Yz;
            this.Yd = Yd;
            this.Cz = Cz;
            this.Fz = Fz;
            this.qT = qT;
            this.Kt = Kt;
            this.Qs = Qs;
            this.Sds = Sds;
            this.r = r;

        }

        public double genislikDeger1 { get; set; }
        public double genislikDeger2 { get; set; }
        public double genislikDeger3 { get; set; }
        public double genislikDeger4 { get; set; }
        public double yukselikDeger1 { get; set; }
        public double yukselikDeger2 { get; set; }
        public double yukselikDeger3 { get; set; }
        public double yukselikDeger4 { get; set; }
        public double ust { get; set; }
        public double kUst { get; set; }
        public double L { get; set; }
        public double Yb { get; set; }
        public double Yz { get; set; }
        public double Yd { get; set; }
        public double Cz { get; set; }
        public double Fz { get; set; }
        public double qT { get; set; }
        public double Kt { get; set; }
        public double Qs { get; set; }
        public double Sds { get; set; }
        public double r { get; set; }
    }
```

If I set the variable like this;
***Form1.cs***

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Class1 obj = new Class1();
obj.yukselikDeger1 = 25;
}
```

And if I call this variable that I changed before;
***Form2.cs***

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Class1 obj = new Class1();
MessageBox.Show(obj.yukselikDeger1 + "");
}
```

resut is like this;

[image]

Comment: Totally expected. They are two different instances of the class. If you want to share one instance, you have to explictly do so. I am guessing you are not using Dependency Injection, so I'd probably use a static Factory or Holder.

Comment: Your `Class1 obj` in the two methods are not the same. In each of the methods, you create a `new Class1()`. You'll have to pass a reference to show the value.

Comment: First of all thank you 
how can I solve this problem Is this make sense if I use in Form2.class like this:
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
Messagebox.Show(frm1.obj.yukselikdeger1+" "); // Consider that I have a "obj" in Form1.class

Comment: @sarac This would introduce a dependency between Form2 and Form1 which is not desirable and on top of that, it would be a "2-hop" property access, which is also not so great.

Comment: ^^ Obviously, "Class1" can be considered your "Application Model" which should be shared by all Forms. That means, you either can make it a Singleton or you keep it as is and create a Singleton Holder class, from which it is easier to refactor to dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I'd recommend you use a Singleton Provider to share one instance of `Class1` to serve as your Application Model:

```
public static class AppModelProvider{
     // static readonly property => will always return the same instance of Class1
     public static Class1 Model {get;} = new Class1();
}
```

Then you can get the model in each of your Forms:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 obj = AppModelProvider.Model;
    obj.yukselikDeger1 = 25;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 obj = AppModelProvider.Model;
    MessageBox.Show(obj.yukselikDeger1 + "");
}
```

This is somewhat similar to the "Resource Locator" (Anti-)Pattern which nowadays mostly would be thrown out in favor of dependency injection. But to just solve your issue, this should be fair enough for now and easy enough to refactor later on.

Comment: You are awesome man that solved whole problems
cheers

Answer (score 3):

You are creating two separated instances. The values are not kept between instances - they occupy two separate and distinct memory blocks.

If you want to share the same instance between `Form1` and `Form2`, you'll have to inject it into the constructor of `Form2`, like so.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Class1 _class1Obj;
    public Form2(Class1 class1Obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _class1Obj = class1Obj;
    }
}
```

Remember that you have to initialize `Class1` on your `Form1`, either as a class object, or just before calling `Form2`.

Also, if your `Class1` is supposed to hold values shared between every class on your application, consider implementing the [singleton pattern](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton).